# How do I get or set a static property on an instance of a class in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For example, I have multiple classes like so:

MyClassA.propertyAlpha
MyClassB.propertyTango
MyClassC.propertyBravo
MyClassD.propertyBeta
MyClassE.propertyCharlie
MyClassF.propertyRoger
MyClassG.propertyWilco

I get an instance of a class of one of the above types and a name of a static property (doesn't matter why).

How do I get or set the static property with just that information (doesn't matter why)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the value directly on the instance.  It is a property of its class, hence it must be accessed on that.

There are two ways to do this.

Either use the `constructor` property:

```
function getStaticProperty( instance:Object, property:String ) : * {
    return instance.constructor[property];
}
```

Or use `getQualifiedClassName` and `getDefinitionByName` to get the class, *then* get the property value:

```
function getStaticProperty( instance:*, property:String ) : * {
    var className:String = getQualifiedClassName( instance ).replace("::",".");
    var clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName( className ) as Class;
    return clazz[property];
}
```